# Testing custom validation functions independently of models in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, validation, custom-validators

I'm building a custom validation method for use in my rails app. The type of validator I want to build compares a column in the model where the validator is called to columns in other tables. The following is a code example that illustrates the pattern of the validator I am trying to build.

```
module ActiveModel
    module Validations
        module ClassMethods
            # example: validate_a_column_with_regard_to_other_tables :column, tables: { table_one: :some_column }
            def validate_a_column_with_regard_to_other_tables(*attr_names)
                validates_with WithRegardToOtherTablesValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
            end
        end

        class WithRegardToOtherTablesValidator < EachValidator
            def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
                # compare record, attribute or value to all records that match table: :column in :tables
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It is possible to test this using the models that exist in the app and schema. However, this is not a good way to test the validator because it would describe the validator as being dependent on models that it is not dependent on.

The only other way I can think of is to create a set of mock up models in the test.

```
class ValidateModel < BaseModel
    validate_a_column_with_regard_to_other_tables :column, :tables { compare_to_model: :some_column }
end

class CompareToModel < BaseModel
    attr_accessor :some_column
end
```

However, it is not possible to validate that :column has something to do with :some_column in :compare_to_model because :compare_to_model is not part of the schema.

How do you create a mock model that is part of your schema in tests?
Or is there a better way to test a custom validator function like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `rspec` you could set up something like this:

```
before(:all) do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :compare_to_model do |t|
    t.string :some_column
    t.timestamps
  end
end

it "validates like it should" do
  ...
end

after(:all) do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table :compare_to_model
end
```

- One note on `before(:all)` it is a "global" setup so the data would persist from one `it` to the other, you might want to wrap each `it` with a transaction and roll it back after or instead have a `before(:each)` that will clean the table.

Comment: Great answer! I am using Test::Unit. The functions `def setup` and `def teardown` will work instead of `before(:all)` and `after(:all)`. These functions will actually wrap each `test`, which is the Test::Unit equivalent of rspec's `it`.